# guardar un resultado de python como tabla de CSV

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Estoy practicando un modelo de machine learning y me da un resultado de 40 observaciones con tres columnas. lo que quiero hacer es crear un archivo de Csv que me permita guardar en forma tabla y poder hacer algo después con los datos.

este es el resultado que me da:

```
print("R cuadrado: ", r2_score(y_test, predictions), " Solver: ", solver, " Layers: ", layer, " 
       Alpha", alpha)
 resultadogrupo=print("R cuadrado: ", r2_score(y_test, predictions), " Solver: ", solver, " 
       Layers: ", layer, " Alpha", alpha)
```

Resultado

```
R cuadrado:  0.9531479532543097  Solver:  lbfgs  Layers:  100  Alpha 0.1
 R cuadrado:  0.932950621878665  Solver:  adam  Layers:  100  Alpha 0.1
 R cuadrado:  0.932950621878665  Solver:  adam  Layers:  100  Alpha 0.1
```

utilizo el siguiente código para crear el CVS con la información de arriba:

```
resultadogrupo = pd.DataFrame(resultados.append(resultadogrupo), columns = ['R cuadrado:', 
 'Solver:', 'Layers:', 'Alpha:'], rows = ['solver', 'layer', 'alpha'])
 resultadogrupo.to_csv('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/PROYECTOS DE PYTHON/DATA SCIENCE AVANZADO/DATA 
 SCIENTIST PARA PYTHON/resultadogrupo.csv')
```

y genera el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rows'
```

Si lo hago sin los rows me genera el archivo solo con el nombre de las columnas pero sin información.

Como puedo crear el bendito archivo con la información generada separada por columnas.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de `rows`, el parámetro debe llamarse `data`

```py
resultadogrupo = pd.DataFrame(
    data = resultados.append(resultadogrupo),
    columns = [
        'R cuadrado:', 'Solver:', 'Layers:', 'Alpha:'
    ]
)
resultadogrupo.to_csv('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/PROYECTOS DE PYTHON/DATA SCIENCE AVANZADO/DATA 
 SCIENTIST PARA PYTHON/resultadogrupo.csv')
```

Comment: Baruch, lo intente como de dices pero no pude crear el archivo CSV.

Comment: Intenta quitando el nombre al primer parámetro: data =

Answer (score 0):

Como te has dado cuenta el problema es el argumento `row`. La traza de error significa que al construir tu dataframe, le has pasado un argumento que no existe. Es decir `row` no existe y por tanto tu no puedes usar un argumento que no existe en una función o una clase.

El argumento que debes usar es `index` para cambiar el nombre de las filas, de tal forma que **la parte del código en el que creas el DataFrame** quedaría así:

```
resultadogrupo = pd.DataFrame(resultados.append(resultadogrupo), columns = ['R cuadrado:', 
 'Solver:', 'Layers:', 'Alpha:'], index = ['solver', 'layer', 'alpha'])
```

Comment: Lo que busco es que el resultado se guarde como un archivo de CSV con los resultados indicados. no busco cambiar el nombre a columnas o filas.